# I can’t get data from an array embedded in json. Using retrofit and GSON

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit

I’ve been trying to get data from the "content" array for several days now, but I get a null response

My JSON:

```
{
   "Magazines":[
      {
         "Title":"someTitle",
         "Year":"2019",
         "Description":"someDescription",
         "Type":"anyType",
         "Cover":"http://img.timeinc.net/time/magazine/archive/covers/1956/1101560514_400.jpg",
         "Info":"infoAboutMagazine",
         "Content":[
            {
               "ArticleTitle":"someArticleTitle",
               "ArticlePrice":"101$"
            },
            {
               "ArticleTitle":"1.2)someArticleTitle",
               "ArticlePrice":"102$"
            },
            {
               "ArticleTitle":"1.3)someArticleTitle",
               "ArticlePrice":"103$"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
        "Title":"someTitle2",
        ...
        "Content":[{
          ...
         }] 
       }
             ]
     }
```

My POJO

```
-----------------------------------Content.java-----------------------------------



import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Content {

@SerializedName("ArticleTitle")
@Expose
private String articleTitle;
@SerializedName("ArticlePrice")
@Expose
private String articlePrice;

public String getArticleTitle() {
return articleTitle;
}

public void setArticleTitle(String articleTitle) {
this.articleTitle = articleTitle;
}

public String getArticlePrice() {
return articlePrice;
}

public void setArticlePrice(String articlePrice) {
this.articlePrice = articlePrice;
}

}
-----------------------------------Magazines.java-----------------------------------


import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Magazines {

@SerializedName("Magazines")
@Expose
private List<Magazine> magazines = null;

public List<Magazine> getMagazines() {
return magazines;
}

public void setMagazines(List<Magazine> magazines) {
this.magazines = magazines;
}

}
-----------------------------------Magazine.java-----------------------------------


import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Magazine {

@SerializedName("Title")
@Expose
private String title;
@SerializedName("Year")
@Expose
private String year;
@SerializedName("Description")
@Expose
private String description;
@SerializedName("Type")
@Expose
private String type;
@SerializedName("Cover")
@Expose
private String cover;
@SerializedName("Info")
@Expose
private String info;
@SerializedName("Content")
@Expose
private List<Content> content = null;

public String getTitle() {
return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
this.title = title;
}

public String getYear() {
return year;
}

public void setYear(String year) {
this.year = year;
}

public String getDescription() {
return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
this.description = description;
}

public String getType() {
return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
this.type = type;
}

public String getCover() {
return cover;
}

public void setCover(String cover) {
this.cover = cover;
}

public String getInfo() {
return info;
}

public void setInfo(String info) {
this.info = info;
}

public List<Content> getContent() {
return content;
}

public void setContent(List<Content> content) {
this.content = content;
}

}
```

My Activity

```
public class LastMagazineContentActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ContentListView {
    private RecyclerView rvContent;
    private AdapterContent adapter;
    private ContentListPresenter presenter;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private List<Content> content;
    private static final String TAG = LastMagazineContentActivity.class.getName();

    public static LastMagazineContentActivity newInstance() {
        return new LastMagazineContentActivity();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_last_magazine_content);
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_content_magazine);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.arrow_left_black);
        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        TextView contentTopTitle = findViewById(R.id.contentTitleNumberMagazine);
        content = new ArrayList<>();
        presenter = new ContentListPresenter(this);
        rvContent = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_content);
        rvContent.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager rvContentManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        rvContent.setLayoutManager(rvContentManager);

        adapter = new AdapterContent();
        adapter.setContent(new ArrayList<Content>(), this);
        rvContent.setAdapter(adapter);
        presenter.loadDateContent();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        presenter.disposeDisposable();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
    @Override
    public void showDataContent(List<Content> content) {
        adapter.setContent(content, this);
    }
    @Override
    public void showError() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Ошибка загрузки содержимого", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

My Adapter

```
public class AdapterContent extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterContent.AdapterContentViewHolder> {
    private List<Content> content;
    private Context context;

    public List<Content> getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(List<Content> content, Context context) {
        this.content = content;
        this.context = context;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public AdapterContentViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        int layoutWithArticle = R.layout.content_item;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View currentView = inflater.inflate(layoutWithArticle, parent, false);
        AdapterContentViewHolder adapterContentViewHolder = new AdapterContentViewHolder(currentView);
        return adapterContentViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AdapterContentViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Content currentDataMagazine = content.get(position);

        holder.contentArticleTitleView.setText(currentDataMagazine.getArticleTitle());
        holder.article_priceView.setText(currentDataMagazine.getArticlePrice());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if(content == null) return 0;
        return content.size();
    }
    class AdapterContentViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView contentArticleTitleView;
        private TextView article_priceView;

        public AdapterContentViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            contentArticleTitleView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contentArticleTitle);
            article_priceView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.article_price);
        }
    }
}
```

My Presenter

```
public class ContentListPresenter {
    private CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable;
    private ContentListView view;

    public ContentListPresenter(ContentListView view) {
        this.view = view;
    }
    public void loadDateContent() {
        ApiMagazine apiMagazine = ApiMagazine.getInstance();
        ApiService apiService = apiMagazine.getApiService();
        compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();
        Disposable disposable = apiService.getContent()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Consumer<Magazine>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(Magazine magazine) throws Exception {
                        view.showDataContent(magazine.getContent());
                    }
                }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                        view.showError();
                    }
                });
        compositeDisposable.add(disposable);
    }

    public void disposeDisposable() {
        if (compositeDisposable != null) {
            compositeDisposable.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

And myPresenterView

```
public interface ContentListView {
    void showDataContent(List<Content> content);
    void showError();
}
```

When switching to activity, the required data is not displayed. After trying to check the output, it returns `"Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size ()' on a null object reference"` and resets the page. After checking it showed that here: `AdapterContent.getItemCount - null`
This is my first app, so everything is hard. I hope anyone will give me a hand.

**Added by ApiService**

```
public interface ApiService {
    @GET("test.json")
    Observable<Magazine> getContent();
    @GET("test.json")
    Observable<Magazines> getMagazines();
}
```

and ApiMagazine

```
public class ApiMagazine {
    private static ApiMagazine apiMagazine;
    private static Retrofit retrofit;
    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://test.satird.ru/";

    private ApiMagazine() {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .build();
    }
    public static ApiMagazine getInstance() {
        if (apiMagazine == null) {
            apiMagazine = new ApiMagazine();
        }
        return apiMagazine;
    }
    public ApiService getApiService() {
        return retrofit.create(ApiService.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you do a little more?

Comment: try with passing the list through the constructor.

Comment: add a breakpoint at the showDataContent() method and check the size of the list.

Comment: When added breakpoint at the showDataContent() , returns content: null
But why?

Comment: Where is your API code? Add `apiService.getMagazine()` implementation

Comment: Added by ApiService

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your API service implementation is wrong. It's never give you either **`Magazine`** or **`Content`**. It actually gives you **`Magazines`** always.

```
@GET("test.json")  
Observable<Magazines> getMagazines();
```

This give you an **`Magazines`** object which contains list of **`Magazine`**. Then inside each Magazine there are list of **`Content`**.

According your current `JSON` structure you neither get `Content` or `Magazine` directly.

Is there any other API rather than `@GET("test.json")`. You have used the same API to get `Magazine` and `Content` which is also not correct.

`@GET("test.json")` always return **test.json** either you call `Observable<Magazine> getMagazine();` or `Observable<Magazine> getContent();`. There is no difference.

Right now whatever you can do is that, call `getMagazines()` from presenter
instead of `getContent()` and parse contents from this like below:

```
public void loadDateContent() {
    ApiMagazine apiMagazine = ApiMagazine.getInstance();
    ApiService apiService = apiMagazine.getApiService();
    compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();
    Disposable disposable = apiService.getMagazines()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Consumer<Magazines>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(Magazines magazines) throws Exception {
                    //This will return Contents [1.*] of first Magazine [Акушерство и геникология]
                    List<Content> contents = magazines.getMagazines().get(0).getContent();
                    view.showDataContent(contents);
                }
            }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                    view.showError();
                }
            });
    compositeDisposable.add(disposable);
}
```

Comment: I apologize for misleading the current POJO. In order not to collect parts of the code from separate classes, I dropped JSON at http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ and simply copied the data from there, forgetting to replace the current ones that I use in the project.
Now I edited to the current state.

Could you explain in more detail why it is bad to use one api for all data?

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: Thank you) Your answer worked!
But, apparently, due to the fact that `.get (0) ` costs, the result returns the "Content" data of the first magazine. Can this be fought?
And yes, I will mark your answer as a solution, thanks again!

Comment: What do you want? All the contents at a time?

Comment: I will explain what I need.
I get nested JSON with a list of magazines. At the first level, JSON is the title, year, etc. The second level is content with articleTitle and priceArticle.
In the first activity, I display a list of magazines with the cover and the name of the magazine (using recyclerview), and in the next activity I transfer the data from the magazine that I clicked on - the description, information and other data from the first JSON attachment. And finally, in the third activity, I created a new view of the processor with data from the "Content" - articleTitle, articlePrice.

Comment: To pass "Content" the desired magazine position that I clicked, I think to try passing `.get (position)` from the first adapter?
Or maybe some other ideas?

Thanks again for looking at my answers!

Comment: My suggestion: First show a Magazine list, and then when click on Magazine, show it's Content. Thanks

Comment: Your approach is correct. Pass data from adapter to the Activity where you want to show.